# Drupal 8 Twig, subcategory, taxonomy

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 website and i got one problem here.

I use twig to set all pages (`page.html.twig`)
then I make taxonomy "flowers" `for url`www.example.com/flowers/
I make for this url specific TWIG - `page--flowers.html.twig.`

But now we are going to my problem...
I need to have subcategory for this category "flowers" have url for it - `www.example.com/flowers/type` <-- but this "type" is always different, like
`www.example.com/flowers/roses` or
`www.example.com/flowers/tulip`

My question is: How to make twig what will change all these "subcategories" (roses, tulip, etc...)
I cant make twig for each one because there is soo many flowers

Comment: So, what you are asking: What filename should the twig file have, to address your sub category taxonomy terms?

Comment: What about `taxonomy-term--flowers.html.twig`? (I assume that the vocabulary with your flowers as sub categories has a machine name of `flowers`). See here for documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions

Comment: Ye, i tried that. But didnt work for me. my full URL is 
https://example.cloud/atlas-rostlin/balkonove-rostliny
I made taxonomy-term--atlas-rostlin.html.twig
But without changes :/

Comment: Be sure, that atlas-rostlin is the **machine** name of the vocabulary. If you change the name of a vocabulary, the machine name is not changed automatically

Comment: That leaves the question. Is "Flowers" the name of your vocabulary? Or is it a taxonomy term with sub terms (rose, tulips) etc.?

Comment: Did you clear the template cache afterwards?

Comment: See here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates and here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/locating-template-files-with-debugging for your chance to debug the templating naming conventions

Comment: Yes, cleared. Machine name is: atlas_rostlin
you can see page with categories 
https://nasekrasnazahrada-cz.hellit.cloud/atlas-rostlin/
and i want this same at every category, when you click on it you can try it

Comment: thank yunzen, i am going to try this urls